# How to get a list of dictionaries from the following code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I need to get a list of dictionaries. The dictionary is created from two different lists where one is a list of lists. I am only getting the last iteration result as output. May I know what mistake I have done in the following code? Thank you so much in advance.

```
d = ['Good','Bad','Lazy']
main_list=[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
dict2={"eventType": "custom Event Name", "attribute1": "value"}
list1=[]

for item in main_list:
    dict2.update(dict(zip(d,item)))
    list1.append(dict2)

print("LIST: ",list1)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
 LIST:  [{'eventType': 'custom Event Name', 'attribute1': 'value', 'Good': 0, 'Bad': 1, 'Lazy': 2}, {'eventType': 'custom Event Name', 'attribute1': 'value', 'Good': 3, 'Bad': 4, 'Lazy': 5}, {'eventType': 'custom Event Name', 'attribute1': 'value', 'Good': 6, 'Bad': 7, 'Lazy': 8}]
```

OUTPUT THAT I GOT:

```
LIST:  [{'eventType': 'custom Event Name', 'attribute1': 'value', 'Good': 6, 'Bad': 7, 'Lazy': 8}, {'eventType': 'custom Event Name', 'attribute1': 'value', 'Good': 6, 'Bad': 7, 'Lazy': 8}, {'eventType': 'custom Event Name', 'attribute1': 'value', 'Good': 6, 'Bad': 7, 'Lazy': 8}]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are always updating the same `dict` instance.

A way to solve this, is to create a new local instance with the updated fields:

```py
for item in main_list:
    updated_dict = dict(dict2, **dict(zip(d, item)))
    list1.append(updated_dict)
```

---

As a side note, you can achieve the exact same thing using list comprehension, which yields a more compact (and arguably cleaner) code.

```
list1 = [dict(dict2, **dict(zip(d, item))) for item in main_list]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. When I tried the code, the order of key-value pairs what I am getting as result have changed. is there a way to get the output in the same key-value pair order?

Comment: @anaghapramesh If you care about the order, you can do `updated_dict = dict(dict2, **dict(zip(d, item)))`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line `list1.append(dict2)`, Try this:

```
from copy import deepcopy

list1.append(deepcopy(dict2))
```

Your code works well. the only problem is that you add `dict2` each time to the list, in the next iteration. when you change `dict2`, that will change all the previous items that have been added to the list.

with `copy` module you will create a copy of `dict2` to the list and by changing `dict2` previous items remain as it was, for better understanding put `print(list1)` inside the loop.